# Thailand​ Mathematics​ contest​ grade9 algebra

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, real-numbers

let $a$ be a positive real number such that
$((x-25)^2​-63)^2​=a$ have 3 distinct roots
find the value of $a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking square roots you get:

$\left(x-25\right)^2-63=\sqrt a$ or $\left(x-25\right)^2-63=-\sqrt a$

Add 63:

$\left(x-25\right)^2=63+\sqrt a $ or $\left(x-25\right)^2=63- \sqrt a $

Take square roots again and add 25:

$x_1= 25+\sqrt{63+\sqrt a} $

$x_2= 25-\sqrt{63+\sqrt a} $

$x_3= 25+\sqrt{63-\sqrt a} $

$x_4= 25-\sqrt{63-\sqrt a} $

There will be exactly three roots if two of these are equal to each other.

$x_1=x_2$ is impossible because $\sqrt{63+\sqrt a}>0$

$x_1=x_3$ and $x_2=x_4$ are only possible if $a=0$ but you are told $a$ is positive.

$x_1=x_4$ and $x_2=x_3$ are impossible because one is more than 25 and the other is less than 25.

$x_3=x_4$ is possible if $\sqrt{63-\sqrt a}=0 \Rightarrow 63-\sqrt a=0$ and that will give you your value...

Comment: tomi.Well done.

Answer (score 1):

$((x-25)^2-63-√a)\cdot$

$((x-25)^2-63+√a)=0$;

1) $(x_{1,2}-25)=\pm \sqrt{63+√a}$;

2) $(x_{3,4}-25)=\pm \sqrt{63-√a}$;

$a >0$ :

1) Gives $2$ distinct roots.

2)Gives $1$ distinct root if $63=√a$.

(Actually it is a double root: $x_{3,4}=25$)

Recall: A polynomial of degree $4$ has $4$ roots. Complex roots occur in pairs.

In the above case we have $2$ distinct real roots in case 1), and by choosing $√a=63$ a double root.